# Shows different element values ​with relative and grid in chrome and mozilla

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to find out how far the element in px has shifted relative to its location via getComputedStyle.
I expect the result in FF will be the same as chrome

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30vw;
    background: grey;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
}

#element {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: gold;
    position: relative;
    left: -25%;
}
```

```
<div class="grid">
    <div id="element">1</div>
</div>

 console.log(getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('element')).left);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first put `getComputedStyle` result in a variable and then log it.

```
var elStyle = getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('element'));
console.log(elStyle.left)
```

The Result in Chrome should be the same as Firefox

Comment: This does not work. Have you checked in 2 browsers?